# Standard SQL - Sum arrays in a column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question regarding BigQuery (using Standard SQL).

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Id  Arrays
1   [1, 4]
2   [2]
1   [3, 4, 6, 91]
2   [0, 9, 1, 4, 0, 37]
```

I want to sum the arrays to the following output:

```
Id  Arrays
1   [4, 8, 6, 91]
2   [2, 9, 1, 4, 0, 37]
```

The number of elements in each array can vary. And the order of the summed result matters a lot.

I considered user defined functions in Standard SQL, but failed.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible to achieve by using standard SQL and if yes, how?

It would be great if you can show me a sample code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  id, ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY idx) AS arrays
FROM (
  SELECT id, idx, SUM(x) AS x
  FROM table,
  UNNEST(arrays) AS x WITH OFFSET idx
  GROUP BY id, idx
)
GROUP BY id
```

It first sums the array elements based on index, then re-aggregates into arrays using the original element order.

Comment: Thank you, dear friend. The solution is very neat and cleaver to me. I did not think about using an extra step to sum on both id and idx. I will keep this approach in mind in the future.